# OpenPyXL - DataValidation adding list to the cell (issue)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

This is my code:

```
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,111110,122221,133332,144443,155554,166665,177776,188887,199998,211109,222220,233331,244442,255553,266664,277775,288886,299997,311108,322219,333330,344441,355552,366663,377774,388885,399996,411107,422218,433329,444440,455551,466662,477773,488884,499995,511106,522217,533328,544439,555550,566661,577772,588883,599994,611105,622216,633327,644438,655549,666660,677771,688882,699993,711104,722215,733326,744437,755548,766659,777770,788881,799992,811103,822214,833325,844436,855547,866658,877769,888880,899991,911102,922213,933324,944435,955546,966657,977768,988879,999990,1011101,1022212,1033323,1044434,1055545,1066656,1077767,1088878,1099989,1111100,1122211"', allow_blank=False)
sheet.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add('K5')
```

But then I have this issue:
[image]

BUT if `formula1` list is small ... then all is working fine.....
WHat is the way to add a BIG list of options which will not cause issues(as you can see above)?

Answer (score 0):

Excel may impose additional limits on what it accepts. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oi29500/8ebf82e4-4fa4-43a6-9ecd-d2d793a6f4bf. In the implementers notes there is additional information but I cannot find the passage referred to.

Basically, I think it's generally easier to refer to values on a separate sheet.